# Regression Tree: Error in model.frame

Tags: r, tree, regression

I'm new with R and I'm trying to build a regression tree. 
Data set has been split into test and training set.

Command:

```
DMTree = tree(DMTrain$AmountSpent ~ Salary + Children + AmountSpent, subset=DMTrain)
```

Console:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = DMTrain$AmountSpent ~ Salary + 
>   :    Variablenlängen sind unterschiedlich (gefunden für 'Salary')
>   (meaning: different variable length)

How should I interpret the error message? Why is it a problem to have different variable lenths?

Dataset looks like this:

```
     Age Gender OwnHome Married Location Salary Children History AmountSpent
1    Old Female     Own  Single      Far  47500        0    High         755
2 Middle   Male    Rent  Single    Close  63600        0    High        1318
3  Young Female    Rent  Single    Close  13500        0     Low         296
4 Middle   Male     Own Married    Close  85600        1    High        2436
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to model AmountSpent as a function of AmountSpent

Comment: I think that what you really want is  `DMTree = tree(AmountSpent ~ Salary + Children, data=DMTrain)`

Comment: okay, thanks! This brings up the next error:
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
The raw data is given as a csv list. Do I have to transform the raw data?

Comment: I think you should set `data = DMTrain` and not `subset = DMTrain`. I assume you use the `tree` package and `DMTrain` is the dataset with the cases you want to use to train you model.

Comment: Great, that is the solution. "data" works! In the previous samples, I always found "subset". "data" makes more sense, also following the Help documentation.